# Flot ticks not converting to time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to plot a bar graph with the Flot library with hours on the x-axis. It does not seem to use the code in jquery.flot.time.js. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<script>
function plotSessionChart(chartData)
{
    $.plot($("#chartPlaceholder"), [
        {
            data: chartData,
            bars: { show: true },
            xaxis:
            {
                mode: "time", minTickSize: [1, "hour"]
            }
        }
    ]);
}
</script>
```

The chartData looks like this:
`chartData = [[1458644400000,104],[1458648000000,136],[1458651600000,108],[1458655200000,150]];`

It is showing the ticks on the x-axis. I feel like I'm missing something vital, some basic Javascript understanding. Is it not using flot.time.js?

Also, `$("#chartPlaceholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {});` seems to not be working either. What is happening?